# remove all other shipping method if there's a method having shipping amount zero

Tags: magento-1.8, promotions, shipping-methods

Could it be possible to remove all the `shipping methods` except the one having shipping amount **0**?

There may be a `promotion rule` which will return the amount **0** for shipping, so it must not be removed.

[image: conditional free shipping]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Display only shipping methods with price 0 (zero) if any](http://ermohammadfaisal.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/display-only-shipping-methods-with-price-0-zero-if-any/)

> I'd solved this problem by creating a custom module while the other [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/17877/4426) by Marius is also working if you do not want to create a module.

In my module I'd overridden the `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available` block as:

**config.xml**

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <onepage_shipping_method_available>Excellence_Subscription_Block_Checkout_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available</onepage_shipping_method_available>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

**Excellence_Subscription_Block_Checkout_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available**

```
<?php

class Excellence_Subscription_Block_Checkout_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available {

    public function getShippingRates() {
        $groups = parent::getShippingRates();
        $free = array();
        foreach ($groups as $code => $_rates) {
            foreach ($_rates as $_rate) {
                if (!$_rate->getPrice() > 0) {
                    $free[$code] = $_rates;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!empty($free)) {
            return $this->_rates = $free;
        }
        return $groups;
    }

}
```

Comment: i am used one custom shipping method like free shipping but i have follow your instruction but not any shipping method display in checkout section.

Comment: @BhaveshGodhani: please check if that module in not already rewriting the block(`onepage_shipping_method_available`). Also check if it is setting the shipping price to **0**.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a quick(ish) and dirty way of doing it.
You have to modify the shipping methods template in the checkout process. (`checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml` and `checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml`).

The idea is that before printing the available shipping methods you can loop through them and see if there is one with the price `0`.

So add this piece of code right before `<dl class="sp-methods">`.

```
<?php 
$hasZeroRate = false;
$groupsToShow = array();
foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates) : 
    foreach ($_rates as $_rate) : 
        if ($_rate->getPrice() == 0) : 
             $hasZeroRate = true;//found a zero rate
             $groupsToShow[] = $code; //remember to show only this group
        endif;
    endforeach;
endforeach;
?>
```

Now you need to edit the listing of the shipping rates.

So below this line:

```
<?php $_sole = count($_shippingRateGroups) == 1; foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates): ?>
```

add

```
<?php if ($hasZeroRate && !in_array($code, $groupsToShow)) : //if there is a rate with the price 0 and not in this group then skip the group. ?>
    <?php continue;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

The under

```
<?php $_sole = $_sole && count($_rates) == 1; foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
```

add this:

```
 <?php if ($hasZeroRate && $_rate->getPrice() != 0) : //if there is a zero rate but the price for the current rate is not 0 skip it.?>
    <?php continue;?>
 <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: the same way you can have the clean solution too.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I would suggest using the event `$this->_eventPrefix.'_load_after` to perform some changes to a collection after it has been loaded but in the case of the collection attached to `sales/quote_address_rate` it does not have an eventPrefix that I can see :(

What you could do is listen to the event `core_collection_abstract_load_after` and check the collection instance.

```
public function salesRateAfter($observer) {
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();
    if ($collection instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Address_Rate_Collection) {
        // Check for the entry you want and remove all others
    }
}
```

Since as behind all the shipping rates code it appears to simply load the collection based on an address filter.

```
public function getShippingRatesCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_rates)) {
        $this->_rates = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_address_rate')->getCollection()
            ->setAddressFilter($this->getId());
        if ($this->getQuote()->hasNominalItems(false)) {
            $this->_rates->setFixedOnlyFilter(true);
        }
        if ($this->getId()) {
            foreach ($this->_rates as $rate) {
                $rate->setAddress($this);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->_rates;
}
```